# iPad Screen Diagnostic?

Tags: ipad

I am noticing a slight colour shift in my iPad Mini screen lately. Is there a diagnostic test I could run to see the status of the screen? (I'm thinking something like the battery diagnostic.)

Comment: I do not know of a diagnostic test for graphics or the screen hardware. However, I would attempt to restore (from a backup, if possible) and see if the issue persists. The next course of action would be to take the device to an Apple Store to get an expert opinion.

Comment: You think it might be software related?

Comment: No, I don't. But I do like to try all of my options for making a trip to the Apple Store.

Comment: How does the colour shift manifest itself? Find a nice landscape with trees, grass, blue sky, perhaps a Swiss mountain scene, and display it side-by-side with another device that looks good (another iPad perhaps?) and make a subjective comparison. Adjust the brightness of the iPad screen; adjust the ambient illumination in the room. Is the shift a problem with R, G, or B? (Ex: too little G and trees/grass look sick.) Do large white areas look crisply white, or is there an slight discolouration? Does it get worse when you make the screen brighter?

Comment: The image seems to have a red hue to it when compared to my iphone or my other ipad (wife's). It's not drastic but is somewhat annoying.

Comment: If the image looks wonky on the iPad in comparison to another iPad or display, then something is wrong. Does the colour shift increase as you use the iPad, or is the shift ever-present?